# Can I assign a function pointer to a function with const parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

If i have a funtion `int foo(const int A)`, am I allowed to do the following coding?

```
int (*Mypointer)(const int);
Mypointer = &foo;
```

In addition, am i also allowed to do the following which is without `const` in the declaration of the function pointer ?

```
int (*Mypointer)(int);
Mypointer = &foo;
```

---

Another interesting case is that, if I have `int foo(int A)` and I declare that

```
int(*Mypointer)(const int);
Mypointer = &foo;
```

I was given segmentation fault

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I understand doubts about (2), but why would (1) be illegal?

Comment: Yes.  Just tried it. I found that (1) and (2) both works. Another interesting case is that, if I have `int foo(int A)` and I declare that 
```
int(*Mypointer)(const int);
Mypointer = &foo;
```
I was given segmentation fault. I edited this case in the question

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Violating "const" should give you a *COMPILE* error.  *Not* necessarily a runtime "segmentation violation".  [Apples and oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should both work.

`const` applied to a parameter passed by value has an effect ONLY in function body, making it immutable there.